# Разница между архитектурой и микроархитектурой процессора?

Tags: железо, cpu, процессор, микроархитектура

Есть ли разница между терминами «архитектура» и «микроархитектура» процессора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно под «архитектурой» понимается архитектура уровня набора команд (Instruction Set Architecture, ISA).

Давайте вспомним, что главной задачей CPU является исполнение программ. Согласитесь, что нам не важно, как CPU работает внутри, важно что он исполняет программы, которые мы ему передаем. И не просто исполняет, а исполняет именно так, как мы задумали! Вопрос в том, какие программы может исполнять определенный процессор и какова семантика этих программ. Именно это и определяет [*ISA*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) — какие программы CPU может исполнять и что эти программы делают, а вот [*микроархитектура*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture) определяет, как CPU устроен изнутри.

Теперь немного подробнее.

---

ISA — это интерфейс между CPU и программами, которые на этом CPU исполняются. ISA определяет количество регистров, которые видны программисту, доступные инструкции, правила выравнивания и так далее. Если вы хотите написать программу для конкретного CPU вы берете справочник по его ISA и пишите инструкции одна за другой. Таким справочником, например, является [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html) — в нем описывается программная модель архитектур Intel 64 и IA-32 (это архитектуры семейства x86, которые используются в большинстве современных десктопных компьютерах).

В свою очередь *микроархитектура* определяет то, как CPU устроен внутри. Из каких функциональных узлов он состоит, какая иерархия кэшей, как декодируются инструкции, сколько стадий в конвейере и так далее.

Микроархитектура, не влияет на семантику и результат исполнения программ, но влияет на скорость их исполнения. Мы можем запустить Doom 3 как на старом Pentim IV, так и на новеньком Threadripper — и там и там он будет работать, вот только скорость работы на последнем CPU будет выше.

Кроме производительности микроархитектура влияет на энергопотребление процессора. Например, в свое время Intel запустила линейку процессоров Atom, которая была нацелена на мобильные устройства. Эти CPU реализовали ту же архитектуру x86, но их внутреннее устройство позволяло экономить потребление энергии, что делало возможным их использование в переносимых устройствах.

Микроархитектура программисту не видна<sup>†</sup>, программист работает на уровне ISA. Если два разных процессора реализуют одну и ту же ISA, то они могут исполнять одни и те же программы. Например, AMD и Intel производят процессоры семейства архитектур x86 — именно поэтому мы можем запускать одни и те же программы как на процессорах Intel, так и на процессорах AMD.

Важно понимать, что ISA не отражает реально происходящие процессы в CPU и является просто абстракцией для программиста/компилятора. Например, ISA x86 обещает программисту, что все инструкции, которые он запишет будут выполняться последовательно, одна за одной<sup>‡</sup>. Но на деле современные процессоры исполняют большинство инструкций параллельно и совсем не в том порядке, в котором их записал программист (см. [instruction level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism#:%7E:text=Instruction%2Dlevel%20parallelism%20(ILP),program%20can%20be%20executed%20simultaneously.)). Тогда как же программы работают, если инструкции выполняются в произвольном порядке? Дело в том, что исполняя инструкции так как ему угодно, процессор следит за тем, чтобы программисту *казалось*, что инструкции выполняются последовательно<sup>*</sup>.

В принципе, об этом можно говорить долго, но в целом ISA и микроархитектура — это разные уровни абстракции. Если рассматривать CPU как черный ящик, то ISA — это его интерфейс, а микроархитектура — внутреннее устройство.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sup>Это, конечно, не совсем так. Программист и компилятор могут использовать свои знания о микроархитектуре конкретного процессора для применения определенных низкоуровневых оптимизаций: зная размер кэша можно разместить код и данные так, чтобы они влезали в кэш-линию, зная что конкретный процессор поддерживает delay slot компилятор может использовать эту информацию, чтобы, например, нивелировать задержку ветвления и так далее.</sup>

<sup>‡ Сильное и не совсем корректное упрощение. Хотя, конечно, иногда и приходится беспокоиться о memory barriers, но в целом программа действительно исполняется последовательно для программиста.</sup>

<sup>* Если кто-то знаком с C++, это что-то типа as if rule.</sup>

Comment: Благодарю вас за столь хорошее объяснение и ещё хотелось бы кое-что уточнить. Существуют термины "процессор" и "микропроцессор". К ним можно применить похожую аналогию или всё таки присутствуют некоторые различия?

Comment: @n1kzzz, нет, тут уже другая ситуация: микропроцессор — это процессор, который помещен на один чип. Большинство современных процессоров — это микропроцессоры, так что сейчас эти термины уже стали синонимами. Если вам интересны подробности, рекомендую прочитать вот [этот](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/44740/whats-the-difference-between-a-microprocessor-and-a-cpu) вопрос.